# ACTION_VIEW intent won't open pdf if redirected

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent, uri

I'm trying to open a pdf document using below code. My pdf has been moved and is now located on a different location, so I updated the uri in a newer version of my app and everything works as expected. The old link has been adjusted to make redirects to the new uri but when the intent is launched on older app versions I get a toast which shows the old file name. So basically it cannot redirect to the new uri to fetch the document.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
i.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.old_pdf_link))); 
startActivity(i);
```

Is there a way to fix this without old apps updating or at least modify the code for launching the intent so a future redirect won't have these problems?
Regular website links work with redirects, but documents don't.

Comment: PDF viewers can't and should not handle redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't because intent is willing to view your uri contents not to be redirected to another uri and view the content of the other one, you need to put your pdf in your old uri, or the users need to update the app